# What is the color value of UITableViewCell’s default selected/highlighted state?

Tags: ios, uitableview

What is the color value of UITableViewCell’s default selected/highlighted state background? That light gray color. I want to use the same color in a UICollectionViewCell, have a consistent highlighted color throughout my app. I can just use a color picker, but is there no constant for it? That would be much more future-proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS 13 and later, it is `UIColor.systemGray4`. So that is the "future-proof" color going forward.

Comment: Thanks! Color picker confirms it's an exact match :)

Comment: @matt Can you share any reference to the official docs or something?